# elasticsearch error while jhipster project

Tags: jhipster

I am new to `jhipster` and get the below error when I try to run my project:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1184)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1179)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4523)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:377)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
        at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:337)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.rollback(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1166)
        at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:205)
        at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:170)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:196)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
        at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:103)
        at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:83)
        at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2018-09-17 18:01:07.135 ERROR 31400 --- [-erp-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed

liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
        at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:340)
        at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.close(JdbcConnection.java:111)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.close(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1209)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:397)
        at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:103)
        at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:83)
        at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:490)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.getAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
        at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:336)
        ... 9 common frames omitted

18:01:07.136 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [/home/arvind/Documents/sts-workspace2/multichanneApp/build/classes/java/main/com/webbee/b2erp/service/UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Failed to build mapping for user:user
```

Comment: if you read the stacktrace it indicates some issue with the UserSearchRepository's constructor. Please add the code to the question.

Comment: Hii @NathanHughes still i am not able to resolve my problem . i have added some  code below which i am using in my project. can you please help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Prompt Response. Please find the Code attached for your Reference. i am using this following code in jdl file to create user module  Let me know if you need anything else on this.

```
 relationship ManyToOne{

Role{User(login)} to User{login}
```

}
entity Role {
    name String 
}

```
package com.webbee.b2erp.repository.search;
```

import com.webbee.b2erp.domain.User;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

/**
 * Spring Data Elasticsearch repository for the User entity.
 */
public interface UserSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository {
}